# groupByKey in Spark dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Please help me understand the parameter we pass to groupByKey when it is used on a dataset

```
scala> val data = spark.read.text("Sample.txt").as[String]
data: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> data.flatMap(_.split(" ")).groupByKey(l=>l).count.show
```

In the above code, please help me understand what (l=>l) means in groupByKey(l=>l).

Answer (score 15):

l =>l says use the whole string(in your case that's every word as you're tokenizing on space) will be used as a key. This way you get all occurrences of each word in same partition and you can count them. 
 - As you probably seen in other articles, it is preferable to use reduceByKey in this case so you don't need to collect all values for each key in memory before counting.

- Always a good place to start is the API Docs:
  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

  def groupByKey[K](func: (T) ⇒ K)(implicit arg0: Encoder[K]): KeyValueGroupedDataset[K, T]
  (Scala-specific) Returns a KeyValueGroupedDataset where the data is grouped by the given key func.

You need a function that derives your key from the dataset's data.

In your example, your function takes the whole string as is and uses it as the key. A different example will be, for a Dataset[String], to use as a key the first 3 characters of your string and not the whole string:

```
scala> val ds = List("abcdef", "abcd", "cdef", "mnop").toDS
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> ds.show
+------+
| value|
+------+
|abcdef|
|  abcd|
|  cdef|
|  mnop|
+------+

scala> ds.groupByKey(l => l.substring(0,3)).keys.show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  cde|
|  mno|
|  abc|
+-----+
```

group of key "abc" will have 2 values.

Here is the difference on how the key gets transformed vs the (l => l) so you can see better:

```
scala> ds.groupByKey(l => l.substring(0,3)).count.show
+-----+--------+
|value|count(1)|
+-----+--------+
|  cde|       1|
|  mno|       1|
|  abc|       2|
+-----+--------+


scala> ds.groupByKey(l => l).count.show
+------+--------+
| value|count(1)|
+------+--------+
|  abcd|       1|
|  cdef|       1|
|abcdef|       1|
|  mnop|       1|
+------+--------+
```